# How to create a custom refinement panel in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, dataformwebpart

As i am bothered by the unability of the OOTB refinement webpart not being able to show the MM translations i decided to try developing a custom refinement webpart (as a custom webpart in Visual Studio). 
Unfortunately, i already bounced my head to a first problem: i can not inherit my webpart from the OOTB one... 
I just create a new webpart (or visual webpart, none works) and try to inherit but i don't know the namespace...

i tried this:

```
public class CustomRefinements : Microsoft.Office.server.Search.WebControls.RefinementWebPart
```

but i get an error: `Reference to type 'DataFormWebPart' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.SharePOint but it could not be found...`

Edit: ok i had to use à farm Solution and NOw iT works...

Now i can inherit from OOTB webparts but apparantly in 2013 version i need to inherit from RefinementScriptWebPart to have the refinement webpart configuration parameters in web mode. I follow the 2010 example from sharepointblogs.be/blogs/timmy/archive/2011/12/13/… but in 2013 the RefinementScriptWebPart class does not have the GetXPathNavigator() function... Anyone has any ideas?

I van nog het the refinmentmanager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research i concluded that it is not possible to reach a solution this way (inherting from default webparts).

I managed to get a solution via a custom Filter for the Refinements 
http://blog.everydayslaughter.com/2015/07/mui-refinements-panel-in-sharepoint-2013/

it's not yet ideal but i'm still working on it